Как использовать type(i.isdigit()) в сочетании с If или While true?
По условию задачи в строке 'ab7h5m0kl98' необходимо определить все индексы цифр.
Пытаюсь использовать следующие виды кода:
    #Вариант 1
    n='ab7h5m0kl98'
    for x,y in enumerate(n):
            while True:
                 type(y.isdigit())
    print(x)

    #Вариант 2
    n='ab7h5m0kl98'
    a=[x for x,y in enumerate(n)]: if type(y.isdigit())]
    print(a)

Однако терплю неуспех.
Знаю что можно использовать третий, рабочий вариант, но он мне не нравится:
    #Вариант 3
    n='ab5dg6v89dgf954'
    n=[i for i, c in enumerate(n) if c >= '0' and c <= '9']
    print(n)


type вам говорит тип объекта. Для вашей задачи это не нужно, у вас тип всех символов одинаковый - строка str.

Вам не нужен type, он тут вообще не понятно зачем. И while True тоже непонятно зачем вы хотите сюда впихнуть. while True нужен для бесконечного цикла.
вариант с циклом:
n = 'ab7h5m0kl98'
for x, y in enumerate(n):
    if y.isdigit():
        print(x)

вариант со списковым включением:
n = 'ab7h5m0kl98'
a = [x for x, y in enumerate(n) if y.isdigit()]
print(a)


Огромное спасибо

@Altushka-97, если этот ответ решил вашу проблему, отметьте его как принятый (галка напротив ответа).
